# How to return user data from Factory into a controller using Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have a factory which checks the authData of a user, using firebase. I wish to access the users details such as name, email etc, but I can't figure out how to get the snapshot data into an object which I can use. I'm new to Javascript.

this is my factory:

```
angular.module('.....')
  .factory('UserDataService', function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {
    var authData = {};

    function authDataCallback(authData) {
      if (authData) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "/userProfiles/" + authData.uid);
        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          var data = snapshot.val();
        });

      } else {
        console.log("User is logged out");
      }
    }

    // Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

    return authData;
});
```

2nd Attempt:

This time i am able to get the users details, but it won't save into the variable service and is returning to the controller as null. Here is my code:

```
   var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var authObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseRef);
    activate();
    var service = {
        userInfo: null
    };


    function activate() {
        // Add listeners for authentication state changes
        authObj.$onAuth(function(authData) {
            if (authData) {
                // Load the userInfo
                loadUserInfo(authData);
            } else {
                // Destroy the userInfo Object if one exists
                if (service.userInfo) {
                    service.userInfo.$destroy();
                    service.userInfo = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function loadUserInfo(authData) {
        var userRef = firebaseRef.child('userProfiles').child(authData.uid);
        var loadedInfo = $firebaseObject(userRef);
        // console.log(loadedInfo);

        loadedInfo.$loaded()
        .then(function() {
            service.userInfo = loadedInfo;
            console.log(service.userInfo.name);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'PERMISSION_DENIED':
                    alert('You don\'t have the permission to see that data.');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('Couldn\'t load the user info.');
            }
        });
    }
    return service;
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear (at least to me) what you are trying to achieve. Can you try to describe your desired behaviour/outcome a bit more?

Comment: I am trying to access the object "authdata" from a controller which holds the users name email etc... I wish to pass the snapshot into the authdata object

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject your service inside something (controller, service, filter or directive) and from the controller, call the service function.

```
.controller('myController', ['UserDataService', function($scope) {
    $scope.userService = UserDataService;
}
```

Now you can call the function from your controller scope.

```
userService.authDataCallback()
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign snapshot.val() to a local variable `data`. `data` is destroyed as soon as the function ends.

You need to assign it to the "outer" variable `authData`, which you can't because you have a function parameter with the same name.

Try it like this:

```
angular.module('.....')
  .factory('UserDataService', function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {
    var authData = {};

    function authDataCallback(data) {
      if (data) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "/userProfiles/" + data.uid);
        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          authData = snapshot.val();
          //[see comment] var authData = snapshot.val();
        });

      } else {
        console.log("User is logged out");
      }
    }

    // Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

    return {
        authData: authData
    };
});
```

Also you should read up on the return types of service/factory in the docs. What the returned object of a factory does, is basically expose private variables/functions for other modules to access.

Comment: its still returning an empty object.

Comment: within my controller i done this:  var userService = UserDataService;  console.log(userService.authData); and it said undefeined

Comment: aw, crap. It's `var authData = snapshot.val();` in my answer. Remove the `var`! - Edited my answer. Also, if this doesn't work, check if accessing it works, when you set `authData = {test: 'test'};`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the snapshot is correct, the val() method turns it into an object.
Meaning data now contains the values you need. For example data.name.

The service should expose a function for this

```
function sendData() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  // Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  ref.onAuth(function(snapshot) {
     deferred.resolve(snapshot.val());
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Something like this

Cheers

Comment: Yeah its does. But I need to access this data in a controller: for e.g $scope.objectname.name. How can I pass the snapshot into something I can access it from?

Comment: First of all I think the first attempt is closer to the working one I have. I understand the issue. The solution is to expose a function in the service that returns a promise. In that function subscribe to onAuth and when it happens resolve the promise.

Comment: the issue now is that the controller will fire before the factory and the object will return as null

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is in **var data** an object.
You can access fields easily with dot **.field**. For example:

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
   var data = snapshot.val();
   // data is { "name": "Fred", "age": 53 }
   // data.name === "Fred"
   // data.age === 53
});
```

> Depending on the data in a DataSnapshot, the val() method may return a
>   primitive (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object. It may
>   also return null, indicating that the snapshot is empty and contains
>   no data.

Taken from:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/val.html

I hope it helps.

-EDIT-
Use this format to get data in the controller:

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-sandbox.firebaseio.com", "example3");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);

app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
  function($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;

    // any time auth status updates, add the user data to scope
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      $scope.authData = authData;
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: And to return it you must create a global variable empty object like @j2L4e sayed and assign the new value inside the callback. Then return it.

Comment: how can I pass the data variable into an object which I can access from a controller?

Comment: I **think** the problem is that your callback is asyncronous and thats why you get an empty object. Try using your service with .then... using promises may solve the problem, but you have to re-write everything. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q